# How to pass optional parameters using fetch vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript `fetch` GET method to call an API. The API returns data; however, there are optional parameters I'd like to pass in to format the data response in a different way. How do you pass optional parameters using the `fetch` method?

```
async function getText(){
    
    let passageParam = randomPassage();

    //API credit
    let Url = 'https://api.esv.org/v3/passage/text?q=' + passageParam + params;
    console.log(Url);
    //Await - Used with Async
    //Suspend function exeeuction until the Async promise settles and returns its result
    let response = await fetch(Url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'myToken'
         },
        params = {
            'indent-poetry': False,
            'include-headings': False,
            'include-footnotes': False,
            'include-verse-numbers': False,
            'include-short-copyright': False,
            'include-passage-references': False
        }
    });

    if(response.ok){ // if HTTP-status is 200-299
        // get the response body
        let passage = await response.json();
        
        populateUI(passageParam, passage.passages[0]);
        //console.log(passage);
     } else{
        alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
     }

     //Function to input json response to HTML
     function populateUI(ref, verse){
        //strip verse
        document.getElementById('reference').innerHTML = ref;
        document.getElementById('verse').innerHTML = verse;
    }

}
```

Comment: As you receive data from API ultimately it is mostly An array of objects. What do you mean when you say you want to format it dear :)? Kindly elaborate friend?

Comment: There's no such thing as `params` being passed to `fetch`. Allowed arguments are listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request). If it's a get request, you have to just add them to the URL in the form of a query string. It could be helpful to use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) - `fetch(\`${url}?${new URLSearchParams({key:'value'}).toString()}\`)`

Comment: @Adam : Absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `fetch` with `GET`, it's generally expecting parameters be sent via a [**Query String**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

You can try something like this:

```
let passageParam = randomPassage();
let extraParams = '&indent-poetry=False&include-headings=False' +
    '&include-footnotes=False&include-verse-numbers=False' + 
    '&include-short-copyright=False&include-passage-references=False';
let Url = 'https://api.esv.org/v3/passage/text?q=' + passageParam + extraParams;
console.log(Url);
```

Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
let passageParam = randomPassage();
let extraParams = {
    'indent-poetry': 'False',
    'include-headings': 'False',
    'include-footnotes': 'False',
    'include-verse-numbers': 'False',
    'include-short-copyright': 'False',
    'include-passage-references': 'False'
}
let Url = 'https://api.esv.org/v3/passage/text?q=' + passageParam + 
    '&' + (new URLSearchParams(extraParams)).toString();
console.log(Url);
```

And also delete the `params` expression.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a **GET** request to a **URL-EndPoint** using **fetch**. The **URL-EndPint** will always return the same data format every time you call it.

And formatting a **response** is not in our hands in this case. To check all the **response** details, go to the  **network tab** of **Developer Console** (do **Ctrl+Shift+I**), you can see the **response headers** and other related stuff that you have received in the **response** and see if any information is useful to you there itself.